# Multiple alignment in align environment

Tags: align

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{align}
    \dot{V} =&\, \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,1}}\sigma_{2,1} \dot{\sigma}_{2,1} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,2}}\sigma_{2,2} \dot{\sigma}_{2,2} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,3}}\sigma_{2,3} \dot{\sigma}_{2,3} \notag \\
     =& - \left [\sigma_{2,1}^2 \sin^2(x_1) + \sigma_{2,2}^2 x_2^2 + \sigma_{2,3}^2 u^2 + 2\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}\sin(x_1)x_2 + 2 \sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,3}\sin(x_1)u \right. \notag \\
    & \left. + 2 \sigma_{2,2}\sigma_{2,3}x_2 u \vphantom{\sigma_{2,1}^2} \right ] \notag \\
    \end{align}

    \end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Insert `\quad` or `\qquad` after the final `&`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `& \phantom{{}= - \bigl[}`. Also, you should use `&=` instead of `=&`.  Further, use `\bigl[` and `\bigr]` instead of `\left[` and `right]`. This doesn't need to be balanced like `\left.`. Also the `\\` in the last line shouldn't be used. In the last line, use `{}+{}` so that the spacing around `+` is correct.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &= \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,1}}\sigma_{2,1} \dot{σ}_{2,1} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,2}}\sigma_{2,2} \dot{σ}_{2,2} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,3}}\sigma_{2,3} \dot{σ}_{2,3} \notag \\
 &= {}-{} \bigl[\sigma_{2,1}^2 \sin^2(x_1) + \sigma_{2,2}^2 x_2^2 + \sigma_{2,3}^2 u^2 + 2\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}\sin(x_1)x_2 + 2 \sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,3}\sin(x_1)u  \notag \\
& \phantom{{}= - \bigl[} {}+{} 2 \sigma_{2,2}\sigma_{2,3}x_2 u \vphantom{\sigma_{2,1}^2} \bigr] \notag   %% no \\ here
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another version with shorter second line as recommended by egreg.

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &= \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,1}}\sigma_{2,1} \dot{σ}_{2,1} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,2}}\sigma_{2,2} \dot{σ}_{2,2} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,3}}\sigma_{2,3} \dot{σ}_{2,3} \notag \\
 &= {}-{} \bigl[\sigma_{2,1}^2 \sin^2(x_1) + \sigma_{2,2}^2 x_2^2 + \sigma_{2,3}^2 u^2 + 2\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,2}\sin(x_1)x_2  \notag \\
& \phantom{{}= - \bigl[} {}+{}  2 \sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,3}\sin(x_1)u + 2 \sigma_{2,2}\sigma_{2,3}x_2 u \vphantom{\sigma_{2,1}^2} \bigr] \notag   %% no \\ here
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The last line `+` is a unary operator, I would convert it to a binary operator; even if there's nothing before on that line, there is in the expression.

Comment: @Manuel I missed that one. Thanks for noting and corrected.

Comment: not sure why you've used a \phantom at the beginning of the third line when \qquad would probably do as well; if it's really meant to line up the plus just inside the opening bracket, then repeating the string from the previous line, as  `\phantom{{}= - \bigl[}`, would be more appropriate.

Comment: As barbara says, I think in case you are not trying to align anything, then `\quad` or `\qquad` is enough. But that's just a “matter of taste” :)

Comment: what i think has happened here is that the change to get a unary minus in the second line was not back-edited into the code; that's why the extra space when you use the code i quoted in my comment.  if that's really the case, then please fix the code that's shown.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Eh, yes. I corrected and going to sleep now (which is the right thing to do for now) Thanks.

Comment: I'd move also the `2\sigma_{2,1}\sigma_{2,3}\sin(x_{1})u` term to the next line.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I have added it to the answer. :)