# Alignment and line breaking in alignment environment

Tags: align

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\dot{V} &=\, \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,1}}\sigma_{2,1} \dot{\sigma}_{2,1} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,2}}\sigma_{2,2} \dot{\sigma}_{2,2} + \frac{1}{\gamma_{2,3}}\sigma_{2,3} \dot{\sigma}_{2,3} \notag \\
 &= -\sigma_{2,1}\left [ \sigma_{2,1}\sin^2(x_1)+\sigma_{2,2}\sin(x_1)x_2 + \sigma_{2,3}\sin(x_1)u\right ] \notag \\
 & -\sigma_{2,2}\left [ \sigma_{2,1}\sin(x_1)x_2+\sigma_{2,2}x_2^2 + \sigma_{2,3}x_2 u\right ] - \sigma_{2,3}\left [ \sigma_{2,1}\sin(x_1)u+\sigma_{2,2}x_2u + \sigma_{2,3} u^2\right ]\notag \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same as your [previous question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208835/multiple-alignment-in-align-environment)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
 &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} -   ....
```

On the last line to put in a space equal to the equal sign